# Download media File in PHP instead of open

Tags: php

i am trying to make force download of mp3 file instead of open in browser.

i am using the following code.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
readfile($path);
exit();
```

This works fine, But the problem is resume/pause is not work and the total filesize/percentage is not mentioned when download the file.
May i know how to fix this.

Comment: @hek2mgl i did'nt see the same question. please read my description. What problem i have. And please let me know the url of the question if its duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: You need to handle `HTTP_RANGE` and `content-length` headers. Just follow the most upvoted answer below that question and your problem is solved.